# error: type mismatch in argument 4 of `ReadInput' error: type mismatch in argument 5 of `ReadInput'

Tags: pascal, freepascal

При компиляции основной программы, компилятор указывает на строку:

```
PROCEDURE ReadInput(VAR FIn: TEXT; AccepableSymbolsSet: AccepableSymbolsSetType; VAR ReadInputCondition: ReadInputConditionsType; VAR Q1Head, Q2Head: Pointer);
```

в разделе INTERFACE модуля UNIT ReadInputLib; и выдаёт ошибки:

```
error: type mismatch in argument 4 of ReadInput
error: type mismatch in argument 5 of ReadInput
```

Код программы

```
PROGRAM ChangeDoc(INPUT, OUTPUT);
USES
  ReadInputLib;
TYPE
  AccepableSymbolsSetType = SET OF CHAR;
  ReadInputConditionsType = (NoWords, IsFirstWord, EndFirstWord, IsSecondWord, EndSecondWord);
  DataMatchingConditionsType = (None, DataIsMatch, DataIsNotMatch);  
  QueuesReadingConditionsType = (IsEnd, IsNotEnd);
  Pointer = ^Node;
  Node = RECORD
            Ch: CHAR;
            Next: Pointer
          END;

VAR
  AccepableSymbolsSet: AccepableSymbolsSetType;
  ReadInputCondition: ReadInputConditionsType;
  CopyQ1QueuesReadingCondition: QueuesReadingConditionsType;
  DataMatchingCondition: DataMatchingConditionsType;
  Q1Head, Q2Head: Pointer;
  Doc: TEXT;

PROCEDURE SetDefaultParams(VAR AccepableSymbolsSet: AccepableSymbolsSetType; VAR ReadInputCondition: ReadInputConditionsType; VAR CopyQ1QueuesReadingCondition: QueuesReadingConditionsType; VAR DataMatchingCondition: DataMatchingConditionsType; VAR Q1Head, Q2Head: Pointer);
BEGIN {SetDefaulParams}
  AccepableSymbolsSet :=  ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z'];
  ReadInputCondition := NoWords;
  CopyQ1QueuesReadingCondition := IsNotEnd;
  DataMatchingCondition := None;
  Q1Head := NIL;
  Q2Head := NIL
END;  {SetDefaulParams}

PROCEDURE AddChToQueue(VAR Head, Tmp: Pointer; Ch: CHAR);
VAR
  Ptr: Pointer;
BEGIN {AddChToQueue}
  NEW(Ptr);
  Ptr^.Ch := Ch;
  Ptr^.Next := NIL;
  IF Head = NIL
  THEN
    Head := Ptr
  ELSE
    Tmp^.Next := Ptr;
  Tmp := Ptr
END;  {AddChToQueue}

PROCEDURE PrintQueue(VAR FOut: TEXT; Head: Pointer);
BEGIN {PrintQueue}
  IF Head <> NIL
  THEN
    BEGIN
      WHILE Head^.Next <> NIL
      DO
        BEGIN {WHILE}
          WRITE(FOut, Head^.Ch);
          IF Head^.Next <> NIL
          THEN
            Head := Head^.Next
        END;  {WHILE}
      WRITE(FOut, Head^.Ch)
    END
END;  {PrintQueue}

PROCEDURE FreeQueue(VAR Head: Pointer);
VAR
  Del: Pointer;
BEGIN {FreeQueue}
  WHILE Head <> NIL
  DO
    BEGIN {WHILE}
      Del := Head;
      IF Head^.Next <> NIL
      THEN
        Head := Head^.Next
      ELSE
        Head := NIL;
      DISPOSE(Del)  
    END  {WHILE}
END;  {FreeQueue}

PROCEDURE AddDocument(VAR Doc: TEXT);
BEGIN {AddDocument}
  ASSIGN(Doc, 'Doc.TXT');
  RESET(Doc)
END;  {AddDocument}

BEGIN {PROGRAM ChangeDoc}
  AddDocument(Doc);
  AccepableSymbolsSet := [];
  SetDefaultParams(AccepableSymbolsSet, ReadInputCondition, CopyQ1QueuesReadingCondition, DataMatchingCondition, Q1Head, Q2Head);
  ReadInput(INPUT, AccepableSymbolsSet, ReadInputCondition, Q1Head, Q2Head);
END.  {PROGRAM ChangeDoc}


UNIT ReadInputLib;
INTERFACE
  TYPE
    AccepableSymbolsSetType = SET OF CHAR;
    ReadInputConditionsType = (NoWords, IsFirstWord, EndFirstWord, IsSecondWord, EndSecondWord);
    Pointer = ^Node;
    Node = RECORD
             Ch: CHAR;
             Next: Pointer
           END;
  PROCEDURE AddChToQueue(VAR Head, Tmp: Pointer; Ch: CHAR);
  PROCEDURE ReadInput(VAR FIn: TEXT; AccepableSymbolsSet: AccepableSymbolsSetType; VAR ReadInputCondition: ReadInputConditionsType; VAR Q1Head, Q2Head: Pointer);
IMPLEMENTATION
  PROCEDURE AddChToQueue(VAR Head, Tmp: Pointer; Ch: CHAR);
  VAR
    Ptr: Pointer;
  BEGIN {AddChToQueue}
    NEW(Ptr);
    Ptr^.Ch := Ch;
    Ptr^.Next := NIL;
    IF Head = NIL
    THEN
      Head := Ptr
    ELSE
      Tmp^.Next := Ptr;
    Tmp := Ptr
  END;  {AddChToQueue}

  PROCEDURE ReadInput(VAR FIn: TEXT; AccepableSymbolsSet:AccepableSymbolsSetType; VAR ReadInputCondition: ReadInputConditionsType; VAR Q1Head, Q2Head: Pointer);
  VAR
    Ch: CHAR;
    Tmp: Pointer;
  BEGIN {ReadInput}
    WHILE (NOT(EOF(FIn))) AND (ReadInputCondition <> EndSecondWord)    
    DO
      BEGIN {WHILE}
        WHILE (NOT EOLN(FIn)) AND (ReadInputCondition <> EndSecondWord)
        DO
          BEGIN {WHILE}
            READ(FIn, Ch);
            IF(Ch IN AccepableSymbolsSet)
            THEN
              BEGIN {Ch IN AccepableSymbolsSet}
                IF ReadInputCondition = NoWords
                THEN
                  BEGIN
                    ReadInputCondition := IsFirstWord;
                    {Add a letter to the queue №1}
                    AddChToQueue(Q1Head, Tmp, Ch)
                  END
                ELSE
                  IF ReadInputCondition = IsFirstWord
                  THEN
                    BEGIN
                      IF NOT(EOLN(FIn))
                      THEN
                        {Add a letter to the queue №1}
                        AddChToQueue(Q1Head, Tmp, Ch)
                      ELSE
                        BEGIN
                          ReadInputCondition := EndFirstWord;
                          {Add a letter to the queue №1}
                          AddChToQueue(Q1Head, Tmp, Ch)
                        END
                    END
                  ELSE
                    IF ReadInputCondition = EndFirstWord
                    THEN
                      BEGIN
                        ReadInputCondition := IsSecondWord;
                        {Add a letter to the queue №2}
                        AddChToQueue(Q2Head, Tmp, Ch)
                      END
                    ELSE
                      IF ReadInputCondition = IsSecondWord
                      THEN
                        BEGIN
                          IF (NOT(EOLN(FIn)))
                          THEN
                            {Add a letter to the queue №2}
                            AddChToQueue(Q2Head, Tmp, Ch)
                          ELSE
                            BEGIN
                               ReadInputCondition := EndSecondWord;
                               {Add a letter to the queue №2}
                               AddChToQueue(Q2Head, Tmp, Ch)
                            END
                        END
              END   {Ch IN AccepableSymbolsSet}     
            ELSE 
              BEGIN {NOT(Ch IN AccepableSymbolsSet)}
                IF ReadInputCondition = IsFirstWord
                THEN
                  ReadInputCondition := EndFirstWord
                ELSE
                  IF ReadInputCondition = IsSecondWord
                  THEN
                    ReadInputCondition := EndSecondWord   
              END   {NOT(Ch IN AccepableSymbolsSet)}
          END;  {WHILE}
        IF EOLN(FIn)
        THEN
          READLN(FIn)  
      END   {WHILE}
  END;  {ReadInput}

BEGIN {ReadInputLib}
END.  {ReadInputLib}
```

Comment: Вы понимаете что вы не умеете писать процедуры? Процедура-подпрограма(функция так же но в ней только одно число можно ввести, а тут отдельная подпрограмма. Пример:http://labs-org.ru/pascal-7/

Comment: @Witalik Может быть он за прошедший год уже научился.

Answer (score 0):

Вы в строке

```
Pointer = ^Node;
```

программы поменяли смысл идентификатора `Pointer`, в то время как в библиотеке `Pointer` означает стандартный тип.

Для исправления можно выбрать один из следующих вариантов

1. Вместо `Pointer` использовать другой идентификатор, например `PNode = ^Node`, тогда в коде не возникнет неоднозначностей. (Рекомендую этот вариант.)
2. Объявить `Q1Head` и `Q2Head` с явным системным типом: `Q1Head, Q2Head: System.Pointer;`
3. При вызове `ReadInput` привести типы: `ReadInput(INPUT, AccepableSymbolsSet, ReadInputCondition, System.Pointer(Q1Head), System.Pointer(Q2Head));`